# How do edit this jquery snippet so that I am using a background image rather than a background color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have this snippet:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
     $("#button_layer").hide();
    $("#images_layer").show();
    $("#container").css("background","yellow");
 })
 });
 </script>
```

How do I change .css("background","yellow"); to say a background-image like url('image.png');

Comment: Pretty much what you have: `.css('background-image')` or simply `.css('background', "url('image.png')")`

Comment: ... "How do i change it to use `background-image` rather than `background`?" use `background-image` instead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#container").css("background-image","url('image.png')");
```

If you want to set multiple CSS properties simultaneously, pass a hashmap with properties and values:

```
$("#container").css({
    backgroundImage:"url('img.jpg')",
    width:"400px"
});
```

Comment: That worked.  Thanks. If I wanted to add a width, how would i do it?

Comment: `$("#container").css("width","50px");` I hope you're beginning to see a pattern here.

Comment: Oh yes.  I tried that along with the iamge part, but it woudldn't work..

Comment: This is what I did:  $("#container").css("background-image","url('img.jpg')", "width", "400px");

Comment: @ariel You should have a look at the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) There is a description of exactly what you want to accomplish. Nevertheless I will add an example to my answer as well.

Comment: Thanks.  But i got an error using the modification.  It says: uncaught  SyntaxError: Unexpected Token and the line is 105, which is:     background-image:"url('img.jpg')",

Comment: @ariel My bad, fixed it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20850/discussion-between-ariel-and-asad)

Answer (score 2):

Simply change it to:

**`$("#container").css("background-image","url('image.png')");`**